# Web service not responding correctly

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a problem calling a web server from a simple console application that runs on my pc.
The application is really simple: it sends a string to a web service and then it waits for the response success/unsuccess.
The web service I'm calling receives the string and then runs a program installed on the server, wait untill it ends and return the closure code at the calling application (it usually take 10-15 mins).

The problem is that when I call the web service, it does not give back any response and eventually the application waits untill it generates an exception when the connection times out.

I'm actually sure the web service is running correcly: when I invoke the web service method using my web browser, it correcly generate the XML I'm looking for after 10-15 mins as expected.

Also, when I run my application, it correcly calls the web service and I can actually see the program running on the server (and producing the desidered effects).

If I try to manually close the program on the server after short time or just try to run a dummy program that ends after less than a minute, then the application works correctly: it receive the result from the web service and it continue its execution.

This is my local application:

```
public void CallService(string parameters)
{
    WSService.WSServiceSoapClient client = new 
    WSService.WSServiceSoapClient(WSServiceName);

    client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(WSServiceAddress);


    client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
    int res = client.CalculateRunner(parameters); //this is where it waits forever
}
```

this is the web service method i'm calling

```
[WebMethod]
public int CalculateRunner(string parameters)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    Process proc = new Process();

    //[set process options based on parameters]

    try
    {
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        return proc.ExitCode
    }
    catch
    {
        //[deal with errors]
    }
}
```

The problem is that it actually does not give me back any error. My console application just wait 30 mins and then generates a time out exception even if the program on the server takes just 10 mins to end (could verify that from logs it generates).

Can someone help me please?